# Why did the Ottoman Empire gave exclusive trading rights to Venice?

Tags: trade, ottoman-empire, venice

Why did Ottoman Empire decided to give Venetian merchants exclusive trading rights, which allowed them to monopolize spice trade? Wouldn't it be more profitable for Ottomans to allow free trade so that competition from Genoa, Ragusa, etc. would drive prices even higher?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: Did the Ottoman empire grant Venetian merchants exclusive trading rights? When? How was the grant authorized?

Comment: It did happen in 15th and 16th century. It was mostly divide et impera by the Turks, i.e. to keep Mediterranean naval powers from uniting against them. Venetians got privileges they wanted to keep, others envied them . This cooperation largely ended by Fourth Ottoman–Venetian War, there were wars before that but this soured relations.